# Docker HTTP-requests between containers

Tags: node.js, http, docker, request

I'm at the first stage in learning how to use Docker so I'm trying basic things. I've created two Node Express services that need to exchange data via HTTP-requests.

**My `docker-compose.yml` file**

```
networks:
  isolation-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  service1-nodejs:
    build:
    context: ./service1/
    dockerfile: .docker/node.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "10000:9000" 
      - "10001:5858" 
    env_file: ./service1/.docker/env/app.${APP_ENV}.env
    networks:
      - isolation-network

  service2-nodejs:
    build:
    context: ./service2/
    dockerfile: .docker/node.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "10010:9000" 
      - "10011:5858" 
    env_file: ./service2/.docker/env/app.${APP_ENV}.env
    networks:
      - isolation-network
```

`service1` uses the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) to make a POST-request to `service 2`.

```
request({ url: "http://service2:10010/api/",
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                json: true,
                body: { ... },
                time: true
            }, function (err, res, body) {
                if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
                    // success
                }

                // failed
            });
```

The result of this call is:

> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:10010}

Using postman I can test `service2` at `http://localhost:10010/api/` and I can confirm they actually can be reached and work as expected.

I'm missing something but can't figure it out. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[See the document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports). The port 10010 is a host port but not container port. You should use 9000 when you access `service2` container directly.

So just change `"http://service2:10010/api/"` to `"http://service2:9000/api/"` and it will work.

Comment: + you need to link the container into the other

Comment: @JohannesMerz He uses networks and he did get the "service2" being resolved as "172.18.0.3".

Comment: I'm using networks so linking should not be necessary by using the internal port of the container solved my issue

Comment: Really no `:` in the `http//`?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Interesting... I thought I have the colon there and the question was also with the colon...