# Linked docker-compose containers making http requests

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I've been looking on the web for a while and haven't found a solution to my problem which is similar to this StackOverflow question [Docker HTTP-requests between containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046413/docker-http-requests-between-containers). But this answer is already what I'm doing in my computer. I'm providing my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: ecdavis15/tsn-web-server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - app
  app:
    image: ecdavis15/tsn-app-server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
```

In my web container I make an http get request to `http://app:3030/history` or maybe `http://app:3030/rules` but I'm not seeing the request find its way to the app container. What I'm seeing in the browser console is this error message `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I'm not sure why the http request isn't getting into the app container since it's linked to the web container. Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to ping the app container from within your web container?

Comment: How is the request being made? Through AJAX or through server side code?

Comment: Remove the links section, it's not needed for what you are trying to do. Docker provides dns for the same names.

Comment: @TarunLalwani This is an AJAX call. I'm using the axios library

Comment: @Sergiu Yes, I'm able to ping the app container ($ ping app) and curl the app container $(curl http://app:3030/history)

Comment: Ajax call is made by your browser and not by your app. So you cannot use `app:3030`, as the browser has no idea about it. Rather you should use `document.location.host + ":3030"` to generate the url the api is on.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hm that doesn't seem to have helped. In my case `document.location.host` is `localhost:3000`. I just found another SO question similar to mine that you answered a while back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074933/access-sibling-service-from-docker-containers-service. I don't know much about nginx right now. Do you think this tool would help me here? Lastly, I checked the `/etc/hosts` in my web container and can see the app container ip address. Just read though that Chrome doesn't check `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: Try using hostname instead of host. Also Chrome uses your systems hosts file and not containers.  You can use nginx to merge them under one server also

Comment: @TarunLalwani Chrome natively only checking the system's hosts file and not the container's makes sense. Using `document.location.hostname` or `localhost` gets this working. Thank you! I suppose that makes sense too since requests to those localhost ports are forwarded to those docker container ports. No need to link the web and app containers then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you make an Ajax call it will be sent by the browser which is client side and not server side. So when you make a call from `<IP>:3000` to `app:3030` for API, your browser has no idea what app is. So you have few things you can do

### Using host file

**/etc/hosts**

```
<IP> app
```

Then when you browse app using `app:3000`, `app:3030` will automatically point to the correct address.

### Using javascript to determine API url

You can use javascript to get the url that you should be using for api

```
document.location.scheme + "://" + document.location.hostname + ":3030"
```

### Using nginx

You can create nginx reverse proxy

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

   location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
   }
}
```

This will require some change in your code file so that you use `/api`