# docker-compose resolve hostname in url

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Tried looking around but couldn't find anything close to what I need.

I have a docker-compose file with a docker container (`web`) that uses another container's IP (`api`) in its environment variable by resolving the hostname:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ../client/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      REACT_APP_API_DEV: http://api:8000/server/graphql
  api:
    build: ../server/
    env_file:
      - server_variables.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

My issue is that `web` doesn't resolve this variable when it's running. I can ping `api` just fine inside the `web` container but `http://api:8000` doesn't resolve properly. I also tried making HOST=api the variable and building the URI manually but that doesn't work either.

EDIT: I added a complete docker-compose.yml file for reference. I can `curl` the `api` just fine from inside the `web` container, but my app can't seem to resolve it properly. I'm using NodeJS and React

Comment: This should work out-of-the-box.  Can you include a complete `docker-compose.yml` file that illustrates the problem, as text, in the question?  Can you give a specific error you’re getting?

Comment: Made some edits to the original question. The error that I'm getting is `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` which is the app in `web` not resolving the `http://api:8000/server/graphql ` url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue. Apparently, my `web` container was fetching from `api` with the `http://api:8000` URI but my browser doesn't know what `api` is (only the containers do).

I followed the stuff suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987726/linked-docker-compose-containers-making-http-requests) to resolve the hostname on my machine and it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link them using [`network`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    ...
    environment:
      - HOST: http://api:8000
    networks:
      - my-network
    ...
  api:
    networks:
      - my-network
    ...

networks:
  my-network:
```

Comment: He said that he can ping `api` from `web` just fine, sounds like they are linked or share a network already. There's just not enough information in the question to actually answer his question.

Comment: If not defined, a `default` network is created for the stack : https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Containers spun up by docker-compose are DNS resolvable, no need for linking today.

Comment: To expand upon the comment by @QuentinPetel: If you only want to add a container to an extra network, but also keep the link to `default` it needs to be added back manually.