# Docker compose nginx + phpmyadmin seperate hostname

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to set up a docker environment with nginx, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, i would like to know how i can configure it so i can access phpmyadmin via another hostname.

For example to access the site i want to use site.com and to access phpmyadmin i want use database.site.com

my /etc/hosts is configured like this

```
127.0.0.1      localhost example.com database.example.com
```

My docker composer looks like this

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./repo:/var/www/html"
            - "./etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        environment:
            - NGINX_HOST=site.com
        networks:
            - my-network
        command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$site.com' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
    php:
        image: bitnami/php-fpm:8.0.10
        container_name: php
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./repo:/var/www/html"
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
        networks:
            - my-network
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.27
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_USER=admin
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - "8989:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
networks:
  my-network: null
```

my nginx conf looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    ...
 }

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    ...
    location / {
      if ($args ~* _escaped_fragment_) {
        # Pass to phantom proxy
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:443;
      }
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Client-Verify SUCCESS;
      proxy_set_header X-SSL-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header X-SSL-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn;
      proxy_set_header HTTPS on;
      proxy_buffers 16 4k;
      proxy_buffer_size 2k;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:433;
    }
    ...
 }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name database.example.com;
    location / {       
         proxy_pass  http://phpmyadmin:80;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't use site.com as an example for [this reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-https-site-com-and-https-mysite-com-bloc).  I have changed everything to example.com*

1. Change your port bindings so that nginx is binding the correct ports from your host machine `443:443` and `80:80` (instead of `9080:80` and `3000:443`).  Otherwise your web requests will need to include the port, e.g. `https://example.com:3000`.
2. Connect your containers together with a common network (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274843/14707109)).
3. Update your nginx config to proxy the traffic to your phpmyadmin container.  It should be something like this:

```
...
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   database.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://phpmyadmin;
  }
}
...
```

This should result in the following:

- Request to `http://database.example.com` resolves to `127.0.0.1`.
- Web browser makes the request on port `80`.
- `127.0.0.1:80` is forwarded to port `80` in your nginx container.
- nginx proxies the traffic to `http://phpmyadmin`, which it is able to resolve and connect to through the docker network.

You should be able to get `https://database.example.com` and the website working fairly easily after that.  I believe `https://example.com` should work fine once you fix your port bindings.  To fix the `http://example.com` endpoint, change your listener from `127.0.0.1:9080` to just `80` in the nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have changed my port bindings as you suggested, i also created a network connection between my nginx and phpymyadmin container and tried understanding how i should config my nginx.. what issue i am having now when trying to connect to https://example.com and https://database.example.com is connection refused while connecting to upstream.  What proxy_pass should i set for my example.com and why should i set http://phpmyadmin:3306 as proxy_pass for me database.example.com thanks!

Comment: alright that makes sense, i will try make some changes. I also updated my answer right now with the changes i have made and how the config looks now.  shouldnt the proxy be phpmyadmin:8080 since i have that port for my phpmyadmin? i use 3306 for mysql container? Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I meant port `80` for phpmyadmin, not `3306`, updated answer.  For example.com, you're just serving the content locally from within the nginx container (/var/www/html/public) so you don't need to proxy to another container.  Hope that makes sense, feel free to post some updated configuration and I can look at it.

Comment: Two other items I noticed.  You shouldn't need a `root` element on the phpmyadmin configuration in nginx, you're not serving content from the local container.  And you should change the location on phpmyadmin from `/phpmyadmin` to `/`.  You want to serve content from http://database.example.com not http://database.example.com/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, i have updated my answer again. When i try to access https://database.example.com it downloads my /var/www/html/public/index.php file ?? Have any clue why that happens ?

Comment: Seems like it's matching your `example.com` server instead of `database.example.com`?  Make sure you are hitting `http://database.example.com` (http) and not `https://database.example.com` (https).

Comment: It seems like there is some issue with chrome cache, it works just fine on firefox and loads phpmyadmin perfectly :) THANKS!!! Now i only need to get example.com to load also.. it still downloads the index page on load in firefox also ;)