# bitnami parse server with docker-compose give blank screen after dashboard login

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parse-server, bitnami

I'm trying to run bitnami parse-server docker images with docker-compose configuration created by bitnami ([link](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-parse)) **locally** (for testing)

i run the code provided on their page with ubuntu 20.04

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-parse/master/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose up -d
```

the dashboard run fine from the browser on http://localhost/login, but after entering the user and pass the browser start loading then ends up with blank white screen.

[cosole errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQUOZ.jpg)

[cosole errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xaNS.jpg)

here's the docker-compose code

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2
    volumes:
      - 'mongodb_data:/bitnami/mongodb'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=bn_parse
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=bitnami_parse
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=bitnami123
  parse:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/parse:4
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    volumes:
      - 'parse_data:/bitnami/parse'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - PARSE_DATABASE_HOST=mongodb
      - PARSE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=27017
      - PARSE_DATABASE_USER=bn_parse
      - PARSE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_parse
      - PARSE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami123
  parse-dashboard:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/parse-dashboard:3
    ports:
      - '80:4040'
    volumes:
      - 'parse_dashboard_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - parse
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
    driver: local
  parse_data:
    driver: local
  parse_dashboard_data:
    driver: local
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Are you able to send an api call (for example, create an object) directly to parse server (without using the dashboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse-dashboard knows the parse backend through its docker-compose hostname `parse`.

So after login, the parse-dashboard (UI), will generate requests to that host `http://parse:1337/parse/serverInfo` based on the default parse backend hostname. More details about [this here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-parse-dashboard#user-and-site-configuration).

The problem is that your browser (host computer) doesn't know how to resolve the ip for the hostname `parse`. Hence the name resolution errors.

As a workaround, you can add an entry to your hosts file to have the `parse` hostname resolved to 127.0.0.1.

This post describes it well: [Linked docker-compose containers making http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987726/linked-docker-compose-containers-making-http-requests)

Comment: It worked just fine ! ..  Thank you

Comment: I'm running all this on vbox machine and it worked fine, but when i try to run it from external browser it gives me this error :

`POST http://parse:1337/parse/serverInfo net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

what should i do in this case to resolve the link ?

Comment: Neve mind, i changed the env variable **PARSE_DASHBOARD_PARSE_HOST** on the dashboard to my vbox machine ip address and it worked !

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! Glad this works, but also wanted to mention that this may cause issues in other type of configurations. Just in case someone can't get it to work with this environment variable.